# MySQL Query - alternative

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My query is too long (3-4s). Any idea's how make this faster?

```
SELECT u.id AS id_uzytkownika,
       u.login,
       u.ranga,
       u.online_light AS online,

  (SELECT MAX(id)
   FROM uzytkownicy_zdjecia
   WHERE id_uzytkownika = u.id
     AND prywatna =0) AS id_fotki,

  (SELECT fotka
   FROM uzytkownicy_zdjecia
   WHERE id = id_fotki) AS fotka ,

  (SELECT srednia_ocen
   FROM uzytkownicy_zdjecia
   WHERE id = id_fotki) AS srednia_ocen,

  (SELECT ile_ocen
   FROM uzytkownicy_zdjecia
   WHERE id = id_fotki) AS ile_ocen
FROM uzytkownicy u
WHERE u.foto =1
  AND u.plec = "mezczyzna"
ORDER BY srednia_ocen DESC,
         ile_ocen DESC,
         id_fotki DESC LIMIT 42
```

Comment: Try to use `Explain` to find out where you need an index.

Comment: In a short - replace subqueries with [`JOIN`s](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: I tried Join, and it's working well (0,6s) but i had to add GROUP BY or DISTINCT to this and then best time was (2,5s) so its still too long.

Comment: Some more info about your join AND your schema would be nice.

Comment: As mentioned above, it would be nice to see the DB structure including keys/indexes definition to make any suggestions. From my past experience I'd say that it will be faster if the SQL is split to 3-5 individual queries rather than trying to do they all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe explain your table structure and what this query is about? Since the column names are not in English, most readers will probably have a problem understanding what you are trying to do here...

In general, it looks like you have a LOT of nested SELECTS here to the same table - is there any special reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id AS id_uzytkownika,
   u.login,
   u.ranga,
   u.online_light AS online,

(SELECT MAX(id)
FROM uzytkownicy_zdjecia
WHERE id_uzytkownika = u.id
 AND prywatna =0) AS id_fotki,
z.fotka, 
z.srednia_ocen,
z.ile_ocen
FROM uzytkownicy u
JOIN uzytkownicy_zdjecia z
ON u.id_fotki = z.id
WHERE u.foto =1
  AND u.plec = "mezczyzna"
ORDER BY srednia_ocen DESC,
     ile_ocen DESC,
     id_fotki DESC LIMIT 42
```

I've substituted 3 subqueries with a JOIN. The first subquery has a different condition, if you can merge that condition withn others queries you can remove that.

**Pay attention** You have named id_fokta the result of subquery, but the same name has the primary key of uzytkownicy table

Comment: Have you used indexes on your tables?

Comment: @user2828677: That makes no sense. Joe's query should never take longer than yours. It does the same, only in a more straight-forward way. Of course there is a foreign key (and hence an index) on u.id_fotki, yes?  If not then add it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to query the same table with the same criteria again and again. Replace your sub-selects with a simple join. A LEFT JOIN, if it is possible that no matching record exists.

```
SELECT 
  u.id AS id_uzytkownika,
  u.login,
  u.ranga,
  u.online_light AS online,
  (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM uzytkownicy_zdjecia
    WHERE id_uzytkownika = u.id
    AND prywatna =0
  ) AS id_fotki,
  uz.fotka,
  uz.srednia_ocen,
  uz.ile_ocen
FROM uzytkownicy u
LEFT JOIN uzytkownicy_zdjecia uz ON uz.id = u.id_fotki
WHERE u.foto = 1
  AND u.plec = "mezczyzna"
ORDER BY u.srednia_ocen DESC,
         u.ile_ocen DESC,
         u.id_fotki DESC LIMIT 42
```

An alternative way to write the query above is to aggregate first and then join:

```
SELECT 
  u.id AS id_uzytkownika,
  u.login,
  u.ranga,
  u.online_light AS online,
  uzz.id_fotki,
  uz.fotka,
  uz.srednia_ocen,
  uz.ile_ocen
FROM uzytkownicy u
LEFT JOIN uzytkownicy_zdjecia uz ON uz.id = u.id_fotki
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT id_uzytkownika, MAX(id) AS id_fotki
  FROM uzytkownicy_zdjecia
  WHERE prywatna =0
  GROUP BY id_uzytkownika
) uzz ON uzz.id_uzytkownika = u.id
WHERE u.foto = 1
  AND u.plec = "mezczyzna"
ORDER BY u.srednia_ocen DESC,
         u.ile_ocen DESC,
         u.id_fotki DESC LIMIT 42
```

By the way: What is "mezczyzna"? A string? Then this should be single quotes.